# Disable 31st of every month React-native-calender

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

I am working for fintech app, And Want to disable 31st of every month as the salary doesnt get credited on 31st of any month

Comment: Looks like you need an array of dates to disable https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars#Date-marking

Comment: Hey !! Can you specify that you are using npm package or import from npm package ?